# How to solve exponential equation in fortran?

Tags: fortran77

Can anyone tell me how to solve exponential equations in FORTRAN (equation having two unknowns, exponent contain one unknown). I want to find two unknowns:

```
exp(w)*w+(exp(w)+exp(2w)+exp(3w))*(k^4+k^2)+k^2+k^4=0
```

Unknowns are `w` and `k`.

Comment: Do you know, for a start, how to solve it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Fortran cannot solve this equation straight away.

In fortran you have to reinvent the wheel to solve this: you'll have to find an algorithm known to work with equations of this form and to implement it. Of course it can be done, and it will likely outrun most other tools at doing it once you've done, but you'll have to spend so much time programming it that it would be pointless.

Why would you use fortran rather than maxima, matlab, mathematica, or something else?
Any of these can solve this equation with a single command, and (if you need to) plot the result with great ease.